# Loop for pictures to be uuencoded does not work

Tags: sh, uuencode

My mips based shell script does not uuencode the pictures in /tmp. What is wrong?

```
for pic in /tmp/*.jpg; do
    echo  "cat $pic" | uuencode -m "$pic"
done
```

I get this little for e.g. 2 pictures in /tmp as output only:

> begin-base64 644 /tmp/01-20150721100027-01.jpg
>   Y2F0IC90bXAvMDEtMjAxNTA3MjExMDAwMjctMDEuanBnIA
>
> begin-base64 644 /tmp/01-20150721100027-02.jpg
>   Y2F0IC90bXAvMDEtMjAxNTA3MjExMDAwMjctMDIuanBnIA

Comment: echo "cat $pic" will only send the string "cat /tmp/01-20150721100027-01.jpg" to uuencode. If you would like the content it would be `cat $pic|uuencode -m $pic"` (without the echo). That said, the way as described in @deceze answer is much nicer: just execute uuencode without the `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with that `echo`, `cat` and pipe there is just crazy. You just end up with the string `cat /file/name` encoded, not the file contents. You simply want this:

```
for pic in /tmp/*.jpg; do
    uuencode -m "$pic" "$pic"
done
```